# UWP Speech Recognition error when running as Admin

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, speech-recognition

So this is a peculiar scenario. My main application is in C++ and it uses a WinForm .dll written in C#. It is the .dll which uses the `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition` library via the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contract` referencing this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance).

When run normally everything is just fine, but when I run the main application as admin, the call to the `SpeechRecognizer()` constructor gives me an exception with the unhelpful message:

> The text associated with this error code could not be found.
>
> Internal Speech Error.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know your setup, but with the C++ code, are you checking for return codes for any function that returns a value?  This is to make sure you are not assuming your code assumes everything returns without failure, when there is indeed a failure return code you are not addressing.

Comment: The exception happens in the C# .dll when I call the constructor like so
`try 
{
  fpSpeechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(fpRecognizerLanguage);
}
  catch(Exception exReco)
{ Console.Writeline(exReco.Message); }`